# Replace Numbers with dots

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace some ID numbers in my system to clickable number to open the related record. The problem is, that they are sometimes in this format: 123.456.789.
When I use my regex, I can replace them and it works fine. The problem accurse when I also have IP addresses where the regex also matches: 123.[123.123.123] (the [] indicates where it matches).

How I can I prevent this behavior?

I tried something like this: `/^(?!\.)([0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3})(?!\.)/`

I am working on "notes" in a ticket system. When the note contains only the ID or an IP, the regexp is working. When it contains more text like:

```
Affected IDs:
641.298.855 (this, lead)
213.794.868
948.895.285
```

Then it is not matching anymore on my IDs. Could you help me with this issue and explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use negative lookahead at the start and also you don't need to include `g` modifier, just `m` modifier would be enough for this case because `^` matches the start of a line and the following pattern will match the string which exists only at the start so it won't do any global match (ie, two or more matches in a single line).

```
/^([0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3})(?!\.)/m
```

For the sake of performance, you further don't need to use capturing group.

```
/^[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}(?!\.)/m
```

Comment: Thanks, you are totally right. I modified the expression very often and maybe the grouping was left from a state before. I also figured out that /m is enough for my needs and is also fitting even better with the function which I am using to process the outcome of the expression.

Comment: Could I ask you again for assistance? I used your second expression without the `^`, because it would not match with the the string `There is another ID: 123.123.123`. When I do it without it, it is matching again with the IP addresses like `123.[123.123.123] (the [] indicates where it matches).`

Comment: try `(?:\s|^)([0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3})(?!\.)` and get the string you want from group index 1.

Answer (score 2):

Add `gm` modifier:

```
/^(?!\.)([0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3})(?!\.)/gm
```

https://regex101.com/r/pK1fV4/2

Comment: OMG. Thanks. I totally forgot to add the modifiers. Thank you very much. I feel so dump ^^'